# Flutter Bloc no actualiza los datos en UI utilizando patron BLOC

Tags: flutter, bloc, ui

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de pedidos. donde tengo un objeto llamado "Comanda" que contiene un listado de objetos llamados "LineaComanda". Quiero manejar con el patrón BLOC todo el tema de añadir lineas a la comanda, eliminar y/o editar.

Muestro el código implementado.

CLASES:

```
class Comanda extends Equatable {
  Comanda({this.lineasComanda = const <LineaComanda>[], this.mesa, this.zona});

  List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda;
  Mesa? mesa;
  Zona? zona;

  factory Comanda.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Comanda(
      lineasComanda: json["lineasComanda"] ?? [],
      mesa: Mesa.fromJson(json["mesa"]),
      zona: Zona.fromJson(json["mesa"]));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lineasComanda": lineasComanda,
        "mesa": mesa != null ? mesa!.toJson() : null,
        "zona": zona != null ? zona!.toJson() : null,
      };

  Comanda copyWith({
    List<LineaComanda>? lineasComanda,
    Mesa? mesa,
    Zona? zona,
  }) {
    return Comanda(
      lineasComanda: lineasComanda!,
      mesa: mesa ?? this.mesa,
      zona: zona ?? this.zona,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [lineasComanda, mesa, zona];
}

class LineaComanda extends Equatable {
  LineaComanda({
    required this.articulo,
    required this.unidades,
    this.unidadesPendientes = 0,
    this.anotaciones,
  });

  Articulo? articulo;
  int unidades;
  int unidadesPendientes;
  List<String>? anotaciones = [];

  //UI VARIALBLES
  bool isExpanded = false;

  LineaComanda copyWith(
      {Articulo? articulo,
      int unidades = 0,
      int unidadesPendientes = 0,
      List<String>? anotaciones = const []}) {
    return LineaComanda(
      articulo: articulo ?? this.articulo,
      unidades: unidades,
      unidadesPendientes: unidadesPendientes,
      anotaciones: anotaciones ?? this.anotaciones,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [articulo, unidades, unidadesPendientes, anotaciones];
}
```

BLOC:

```
part of 'Comanda_bloc.dart';


abstract class ComandaState extends Equatable {
  const ComandaState();
}

class ComandaInitial extends ComandaState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ComandaLoading extends ComandaState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ComandaLoaded extends ComandaState {
  final Comanda comanda;

  const ComandaLoaded({required this.comanda});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [comanda];
}

class ComandaError extends ComandaState {
  final String error;

  const ComandaError(this.error);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}





part of 'Comanda_bloc.dart';

abstract class ComandaEvent extends Equatable {
  const ComandaEvent();
}

class StartComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class AddLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  const AddLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class AddUnidades extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  AddUnidades(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveUnidades extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveUnidades(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveAllLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveAllLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class SelectMesa extends ComandaEvent {
  final Mesa mesa;

  SelectMesa(this.mesa);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [mesa];
}

class LoadComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda;

  LoadComanda(this.lineasComanda);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [lineasComanda];
}



part 'Comanda_event.dart';
part 'Comanda_state.dart';

class ComandaBloc extends Bloc<ComandaEvent, ComandaState> {
  final Comanda_Repository repository;

  ComandaBloc(this.repository) : super(ComandaInitial()) {
    //EVENTOS

    on<LoadComanda>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      try {
        // final comanda = await repository.getone(1);

        emit(ComandaLoaded(comanda: Comanda()));
      } catch (error) {
        emit(ComandaError(error.toString()));
      }
    });

    on<StartComanda>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      try {
        // final comanda = await repository.getone(1);

        emit(ComandaLoaded(comanda: Comanda()));
      } catch (error) {
        emit(ComandaError(error.toString()));
      }
    });

    on<AddLineaComanda>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          emit(
            ComandaLoaded(
                comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(
                    lineasComanda: List.from(state.comanda.lineasComanda)
                      ..add(event.lineaComanda))),
          );
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<RemoveLineaComanda>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          emit(
            ComandaLoaded(
                comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(
                    lineasComanda: List.from(state.comanda.lineasComanda)
                      ..remove(event.lineaComanda))),
          );
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<AddUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
 
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == event.lineaComanda).unidades += 1;

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: lineasComanda)),
            );
          
          }
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<RemoveUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == event.lineaComanda).unidades -= 1;

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: lineasComanda)),
            );
          }

          // LineaComanda lineaComanda =
          //     state.comanda.lineasComanda.firstWhere((element) => element == event.lineaComanda);

        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

UI:

```
class Comanda extends StatefulWidget {
  const Comanda({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Comanda> createState() => _ComandaState();
}

class _ComandaState extends State<Comanda> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: BlocBuilder<ComandaBloc, ComandaState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ComandaLoading) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
              return state.comanda.lineasComanda.isEmpty
                  ? const EmptyList(
                      text: 'No existen artículos en la comanda',
                    )
                  : ListView(children: [
                      ExpansionPanelList(
                        elevation: 3,
                        // dividerColor: Colors.blue,
                        expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
                          setState(() {
                            state.comanda.lineasComanda[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                          });
                        },
                        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        children: state.comanda.lineasComanda
                            .map(
                              (item) => LineaComandaCard(item),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                        // Card_lineaComanda(flatButtonStyle),
                      ),
                    ]);
            }

            if (state is ComandaError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(state.error.toString()),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ExpansionPanel LineaComandaCard(LineaComanda lineaComanda) {
    //Conusltamos el color de la famila

    Color color = Colors.grey;
    ;

    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state

    return ExpansionPanel(
      canTapOnHeader: true,
      // backgroundColor: item['isExpanded'] == true ? Colors.cyan[100] : Colors.white,
      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
        return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                border: Border(left: BorderSide(color: color, width: 3))),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(lineaComanda.articulo!.nombre, style: AppTheme.tituloCard),
                Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Unidades:',
                            style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                          ),
                          BlocBuilder<ComandaBloc, ComandaState>(
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              if (state is ComandaLoaded)
                                return Text(
                                  ' ${state.comanda.lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == lineaComanda).unidades}',
                                  style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                                  key: ValueKey(lineaComanda.unidades),
                                );

                              return Container();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                        return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
                      },
                    ),

                    const Text("  |  "),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 2),
                      child: Text(
                        'Pendientes: ${lineaComanda.unidades}',
                        style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                      ),
                    ),

                    (lineaComanda.unidadesPendientes >= lineaComanda.unidades)
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.check_box_rounded,
                            color: AppTheme.greenOscuro,
                            size: 15,
                          )
                        : (lineaComanda.unidades == lineaComanda.unidadesPendientes)
                            ? const Icon(Icons.disabled_by_default_rounded,
                                color: AppTheme.redOscuro, size: 15)
                            : const Icon(Icons.indeterminate_check_box_rounded,
                                color: AppTheme.yellow, size: 15),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),

                    // const SizedBox(
                    //   width: 20,
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ));
      },
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 3, left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Text(
              "Anotaciones:",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 30),
            child: Text(
              "· Sin pepinillo.",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              // alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              // buttonHeight: 12.0,
              // buttonMinWidth: 10.0,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(AddUnidades(lineaComanda));

                  
                    // setState(() {
                    //   lineaComanda.unidades += 1;
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Más',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(RemoveUnidades(lineaComanda));
                   
                    // setState(() {

                    //   // lineaComanda.unidades -= 1;
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.remove,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Menos',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.edit_note_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Anotaciones',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(RemoveLineaComanda(lineaComanda));
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.delete_outline_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Eliminar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.local_offer_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Invitar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      isExpanded: lineaComanda.isExpanded,
    );
  }
}
```

**Los eventos de añadir y elIminar linea de comanda si que funcionan correctamente y el UI se redibuja, pero los eventos de añadir y eliminar unidades no redibujan la UI, aunque si que se ejecuta el evento.**

Muestro logs de la consola:

- AÑADIR/ELIMINAR Linea de comanda:

  I/flutter (13260): ComandaBloc AddLineaComanda(LineaComanda(Articulo(389, , BOCADILLO CHIVITO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, -1, 0, -1, SioNO.No, SioNO.No), 2, 0, []))
  I/flutter (13260): Transition { currentState: ComandaLoaded(Comanda([], null, null)),
  event: AddLineaComanda(LineaComanda(Articulo(389, , BOCADILLO CHIVITO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, -1, 0, -1, SioNO.No, SioNO.No), 2, 0, [])), nextState: ComandaLoaded(Comanda([LineaComanda(Articulo(389, , BOCADILLO CHIVITO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, -1, 0, -1, SioNO.No, SioNO.No), 2, 0, [])], null, null)) }
- AÑADIR / ELIMINAR UNIDADES:

  I/flutter (13260): ComandaBloc AddUnidades(LineaComanda(Articulo(389, , BOCADILLO CHIVITO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, -1, 0, -1, SioNO.No, SioNO.No), 4, 0, []))

Alguna solución para redibujar la UI correctamente ???

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No veo el código que pusiste en el bloc.
Solo pusiste el Staten y event.
El bloc es quien recibe los eventos y modifica o no el State. Sería bueno que pudieras también la lógica del bloc.

Comment: Ya está, disculpa.

Comment: Saludos @YuberV, esta sección es solo para respuestas que dan solución a la pregunta y no así para dejar comentarios. Lectura recomendada [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-sitio/3765#3765). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Agrega más elementos a la lista de la función props en el estado ComandaLoaded así puede destinguir la diferencia de un estado similar a otro.

Podría ser

```
List<Object> get props => [comanda, comanda.lineasComanda];
```